# python setuptools - clarification on creating command line application

Tags: python, setuptools

I have created a simple `python3.7.1` command-line application using `click` in a `conda` virtual env that works fine when running as a module `python -m`.

#### End-goal:

To create a single command (binary) executable that can be shipped to somewhere on the filesystem that is preferably not dependent on a python/conda virtual environment.

Note that this question is likely closely tied to my complete lack of understanding of `setuptools` (I have read through the docs).

Project structure:

```
python_clean_repo/
├── README.md
├── conda-environment.yaml
├── setup.py
├── tests
│   └── test_basic.py
└── yourpackage
    ├── configs
    │   ├── app_config.yaml
    │   └── config.py
    ├── main.py
    └── scripts
        └── cmdline.py
```

When run with the `-m` option, everything works as expected:

```
$ python -m yourpackage.scripts.cmdline
Hello World!
here i am in main
config is {'key': 'value'}
```

The packaging appears to complete successfully:

```
$ pip install -e .
...
Successfully installed python-clean-repo
```

So I now have an executable in my virtual env called `yourscript` (which is the name of the entrypoint provided in `setup.py`) which works exactly as I would expect:

```
$ yourscript
Hello World!
here i am in main
config is {'key': 'value'}
```

#### The question is:

How do I "ship" this executable, that now appears directly tied to my virtual environment?  I have also tried `python setup.py sdist` but for some reason the created tar.gz does not contain everything (there are no included `.py` modules, just a bunch of `.txt` files such as `entry_points.txt` and `requires.txt`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a Python script standalone executable to run without ANY dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+standalone+script

Comment: The "duplicate" suggestion references `pyinstaller` which doesnt seem to install into my conda env (tried with both pip and conda).  I still don't have a good enough grasp of the build process around `setup.py` to fully understand if this is actually the thing I need to get the job done and I just dont understand *how* to use it.